# AngularJS - filter in script src attribute

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

I am trying to use a angularjs filter in script tag. With ng-src directive, I am able to specify the expression that will evaluate into script url but the problem is that the resolved script url is loaded after all other scripts that follows it.

```
<!-- defines myfilter filter -->
<script src="mymodule.js"></script>
<script ng-src="{{'firstscript.js'|myfilter}}"></script>
<script src="secondscript.js"></script>
```

The firstscript.js is executed after the secondscript.js. Is there any way that the scripts can be loaded in the order specified.

Comment: Why are you doing in the filter?

Comment: I was able to get them to load in ordre by making them all ng-src . However it they were getting called multiple times. Can you please explain what you are doing in the filter?

Comment: Fascinating. Curious to hear what you're trying to do with this.

Comment: Using filters to load scripts like that is handy for doing things like running an un-minified version on dev machines (for better stack traces) while using minified code on the production servers for speed. Depends a bit on when the code must load, but in general it's a nice concept.

And as Nix said, they will differ in order because on is ng-src and one is normal src. ng-src isn't run until after Angular is done loading stuff, but the normal src will start right away.

Comment: I am trying to create a filter "asset" that will prepend the Asset/CDN url to the script name. But I should also be able to use some external asset files e.g. jquery, bootstrap etc. that might be hosted on some other CDN so I will need a complete URL for them. I want to enforce the order irrespective of whether I use the filter or use complete URL.

Comment: @Nix the filter is called multiple times because it is reinterpreted for every digest cycle. This it the expected behavior in 99.99% of all cases - or do you mean there are several requests?

Answer (score 0):

I understand that it will be difficult to achieve unless document object has an event that fires before an element is added to DOM and we can manipulate that element's tag in that event handler.

For me, the simpler solution was to use a simple REGEX replace at the backend to resolve the pattern with the full URL.